# How to check programmatically if Gradle task has been scheduled to be executed?

Tags: gradle

I would like to enable a task dependency only if another task has been scheduled. How can I tell if a task has been scheduled to be executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly enabling a task dependency if another task has been scheduled, but using `onlyIf` has a similar effect:

```
task dependee

task depender {
  dependsOn: dependee
  onlyIf {
    dependee.doesWork
  }
}
```